# isomorphism from one vector space to another one

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

This is from my textbook
[image]

I don't quite understand what isomorphism means. Greek word "isomorphism" means same structure, but how can we say $P_3$ has the same structure as $R^4$?

Comment: Did you try looking in the index of your textbook?

Comment: By definition, an isomorphism of vector spaces is a bijective linear map between the spaces. A linear map is compatible with the linear structure of a vector space. A bijection between sets says that they are of equal 'size', hence an isomorphisms between vector spaces says that you have two linear structures of equal size with the same linear structure. Up to the notation of elements, isomorphic spaces are the same in the same way that the set $\left\{a,b \right\} \cong \left\{1,2\right\}$.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Do we not also need the map to be a homomorphism?

Comment: Both the polynomial space and the Euclidean space have additional structure beyond simply being vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$. The isomorphism is simply a vector space isomorphism. It ignores the additional structure.

Comment: @IrregularUser: Morphisms in the category of vector spaces are called linear maps.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Thanks, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

An isomorphism between two objects should be a one-to-one, onto (hence invertible), and should preserve the structure of the objects in question.

When we consider vector spaces, the structure we care about is the vector space structure. You know the vector space structure is preserved if there is a mapping $$f : V \to W$$ such that $$f(a v_1 + b v_2) = a f(v_1) + b f(v_2)$$

Here, $\mathbb{P}_3$ has the same structure as $\mathbb{R}_4$ since you are taking each polynomial of the form $$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$$ to the 4-tuple $$(a, b, c, d) \\ \text{where} \ a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}^4$$