# Find the matrix $f$ with respect of the standard basis of $P_2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus, change-of-basis

I have the following: $V = P_2(\mathbb{R})$, $W = \mathbb{R}^3$, and a mapping $f: V \to W$ defined by
$$
f(a + bx + cx^2) 
= \begin{bmatrix} 
a \\ b \\ c
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now I need to find the matrix $f$ with respect to the bases for $P_2$ which is $\{1, x, x^2\}$ and for $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is $$
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} 
\right\}. 
$$
Every example that I could found wasn't of this form so I am kinda confused how this will be solved one of my thoughts was that for every $f(1)$, $f(x)$ and $f(x^2)$ the answer would be $\mathbf{e}_1$, $\mathbf{e}_2$, and $\mathbf{e}_3$, respectively, but I am not sure if this is correct or how to prove it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Go back to the definition: If a matrix $A$ represents a linear transformation $T: V \to W$ with bases $\{\mathbf{v}_1, \dots, \mathbf{v}_n\}$ and $\{\mathbf{w}_1, \dots, \mathbf{w}_m\}$, respectively, then column $j$ of $A$ will consist of the weights where you express $T(\mathbf{v}_j)$ in the basis for $W$, i.e. for $j = 1, \dots, n$, 
$$
T(v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij} w_i 
$$

Comment: So for this particular case we can say that $$f(1)$$ which is equal to $$f(v_1)$$ is equal to \left\{
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\right\} because the other two variable are coeffients of x and $x^2$ this is what confuses me

Comment: It says you're mapping a vector in $V=P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ to a vector in $W=\mathbb{R}^{3}.$ Hence, for $f(1) = f(v_{1}),$ we must be able to write it as a linear combination of $w_{1}=e_{1}, w_{2}=e_{2},$ and $w_{3}=e_{3}.$ What are the linear coefficients? They are as you found, so the linear sum simplifies to $f_{1}=f(v_{1})=w_{1}=e_{1}.$

Comment: Essentially, the linear map gives the coordinate vector of an element of $V$ with respect to the standard basis of $W.$ It is one part of a commutative diagram that relates the abstract vector space $V$ with $W.$

Comment: I see thanks a lot both of you for the comments

Comment: This is related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771178/isomorphism-from-one-vector-space-to-another-one